# Парсинг строки из нулей и единиц

Tags: парсер

Добрый день. 
Помогите с решением следующей задачи. На вход идет строка из 0 и 1, например, 110100011, нужно распарсить её на составляющие. Например, первые 2 цифры - это одна из 4 команд (00 - команда А, 01 - В, 10 - С, 11 - D). Потом 3 цифры, это одна из 5 команд (001, 111, 110, 010, 100). И так далее. Таким образом, нужно определить, какие команды закодированы в строке.
Вопрос: каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вопрос применительно к какому-то определённому языку программирования?

В общем, сохраняйте переменную "курсор", указывающий на место, где сейчас находитесь в строке. Начиная с 0. И разобрав очередной кусок, сдвигаете этот курсор на его длину.

Comment: @compl, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks)](/users/7161/sergiks), спасибо. Нет, язык не важен. Не совсем понимаю насчет курсора. Нет  ли примера с использованием переменной-курсора?

---

[[@smackmychi](/users/22959/smackmychi)](/users/22959/smackmychi), проблема в том, что я пока не понимаю, каким образом это сделать. Т.е. проблема не в реализации кода, а в идее.

---

Спасибо. Вопрос можно закрыть. В Java есть метод substring, который возвращает подстроку строки. Это то, что мне нужно.